# Split string using multiple delimiter

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, awk, csv

I have a text file which contains below string and I want to convert this into a CSV file.

I want to split below string:

```
location = /example/url/newsite/redirect {return 301 https://example.com/fr;}
```

... to values like as follows:

```
/example/url/newsite/redirect,301,https://example.com/fr
```

Currently I am using the below command

```
awk '{gsub(/;}/,"",$6); if ($1 == location) print $3","$6 }' redirections/*.redirections >> redirect-csv/redirect.csv
```

Ideally, we should not have to specify a filename. It should take all the *.redirections files in redirections/ and do a 1 to 1 mapping to generate files in redirect-csv.

```
redirections/
site1.redirections
site2.redirections

Run the magic command.

redirect-csv/
site1.csv
site2.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is best approached by using a regular expression to match the string against a pattern and extract the relevant parts.

```
echo "location = /example/url/newsite/redirect {return 301 https://example.com/fr;}" |
  sed -n 's/^location = \(.*\) {return \(3[[:digit:]]\{2\}\) \(.*\);}$/\1,\2,\3/p'
```

gives

```
/example/url/newsite/redirect,301,https://example.com/fr
```

Or if the fields may contain characters that are special in the CSV format (like `,`, `"`):

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$c = Text::CSV->new}
  if (/^location = (.*) \{return (3\d\d) (.*);\}$/) {
    $c->print(STDOUT, [$1, $2, $3])
  }'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following your change, here is a solution based on the first one

```
for file in redirections/*.redirection; do fname=$(basename $file); awk '{gsub(/;}/,"",$6); print $3" & "$5" & "$6 }' $file > redirect-csv/${fname/.redirection/.csv}; done
```

Comment: Thanks @darxmurf - Currently I am using the "for my_file in redirections/*.redirections;
do fname=$(basename $my_file);
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/${fname%redirections}csv
done" 
this command but I am unable to add "if ($1 == location)" this condition in above command, do you have any suggestion for it.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, if this line is always following the same model, one line with awk ?

```
echo "location = /example/url/newsite/redirect {return 301 https://example.com/fr;}" | awk '{gsub(/;}/,"",$6); print $3" & "$5" & "$6 }'
```

to redirect that in "myfile.csv"

```
awk '{gsub(/;}/,"",$6); print $3" & "$5" & "$6 }' list.txt >> myfile.csv
```

where list.txt contains your lines

Comment: Thanks @darxmurf, but how can I write this values to CSV using awk, do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Well, if your lines are in "list.txt":

awk '{gsub(/;}/,"",$6); print $3" & "$5" & "$6 }' list.txt >> myfile.csv

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it really helps me a lot.

Comment: Can we write multiple awk commands in file & execute that file ?

Comment: euh, yes, just open a file, paste your awk commands line by line and then execute your file

Comment: I have also modified the question, can you please have a look & suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

if the pattern is known and its always the same then `awk` and `tr` could help:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$5,$6}' site1.redirections | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/site1.csv
```

`awk` will make the csv with comma as saperator and then `tr` will eliminate the uneeded characters. Finaly the redirection of your output will go to the needed file.

**edit1**:
for iterate over multiple files and manipulate the file name with similar consideration that name follows a pattern:

```
for my_file in site*.redirections;do
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$5,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/$(echo $my_file | cut -d. -f1).csv
done
```

**edit2**:
To redirect output to a file with same name but instead of the .redirection extension to .csv extension:

```
for my_file in *.redirections;do
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$5,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/${my_file%redirections}csv
done
```

**edit3**:
Thanks to @darxmurf:

```
for my_file in *.redirections;do
awk -v OFS=, '{if ($1 == "location") print $3,$5,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/${my_file%redirections}csv
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, your code works as expected. but how I can pick up dynamic filename from redirections folder & pass this filename to CSV file ?

Comment: @Yogi have edited the answer with a potential solution that i would personlay followed.

Comment: Thanks @GiannakopoulosJ, I have using the below command & my redirections folder contains 89 file and name of the files are "be.total.com.redirections", "m.total.fr.redirections" & "campus.total.com.redirections"
I want to convert that filename same with .CSV extension added to it
I am using this code ->"for my_file in *.redirections;
do
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/$(echo $my_file).csv
done"
so I have tried above code but it only converts first file in redirections folder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thanks @GiannakopoulosJ - Currently I am using the "for my_file in redirections/*.redirections;
do fname=$(basename $my_file);
awk -v OFS=, '{print $3,$6}' $my_file | tr -d }\; >> redirect-csv/${fname%redirections}csv
done" 
this command but I am unable to add "if ($1 == location)" this condition in above command, do you have any suggestion for it.

Comment: i am lossing you on what you want to achive. you are getting the basename of the file you print with delimiter the two columns and eliminate } and ; special characters. then the output is going to another directory with name csv and file name. what you want to check with location?

Comment: as @GiannakopoulosJ says, it's getting complicated... anyway, for your if statement, try this:  {if ($1 == "location") {print $3,$6}}

Comment: There are some commented lines in files which starts with "#location" so I want only those lines which starts with "location" not with "#locations".
You are right in this scenario, I think I am messing this up. I should use your code with extra condition of "if ($i == "location")"

Comment: Thanks GiannakopoulosJ & darxmurf

Answer (score 0):

1. An error --  this code, abbreviated from the OP's question:

   ```
   awk '...stuff...' r/*.red >> r-c/red.csv
   ```

   ...would input many files, change them, and output a single extra-long
   *red.csv* file.  [The `>>` redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Variants) behaves rather like `cat foo/* > bar/baz`.
2. Using the same abbreviations to avoid word-wrap, with `basename`
   and xargs, generate `cp` commands to copy the `r/` files to `r-c/` while
   changing their names, and edit those new files in-place with *GNU*
   `sed`:

   ```
   basename -a -s r/*.red | xargs -L 1 -I {}   cp  r/{}.red  r-c/{}.csv
   sed -i 's/^[^=]*= \|\;}$//g;s/ [^ ]* /,/;s/ /,/'  r-c/*.csv
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

command:

```
echo "/example/url/newsite/redirect {return 301 https://example.com/fr;}"| sed "s/[{}]//g"|  sed "s/return/,/g"| sed "s/301/&,/g"| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sed "s/;$//g"
```

output

```
echo "/example/url/newsite/redirect {return 301 https://example.com/fr;}"| sed "s/[{}]//g"|  sed "s/return/,/g"| sed "s/301/&,/g"| sed -r "s/\s+//g"| sed "s/;$//g"

/example/url/newsite/redirect,301,https://example.com/fr
```